# Update datasource from control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I'm a bit new to the idea of bindings in C#. I currently have an application using MVVM that I'm working on. Say I have, for example, a list like so:

```
List<string> Items = new List<string>()
{
    "Item1",
    "Item2",
    "Item3",
}
```

Bound to this list are three textboxes like so:

In the XAML:

```
<TextBox Name="TextBox1" text="{Binding TextSource1 Mode=TwoWay}">
<TextBox Name="TextBox2" text="{Binding TextSource2 Mode=TwoWay}">
<TextBox Name="TextBox3" text="{Binding TextSource3 Mpde=TwoWay}">
```

And in the code:

```
Public string TextSource1
{
    get { return Items[0]; }
    set { Items[0] = value; }
}
Public string TextSource2
{
    get { return Items[1]; }
    set { Items[1] = value; }
}
Public string TextSource3
{
    get { return Items[2]; }
    set { Items[2] = value; }
}
```

Say the displayed value in the first textbox is currently "Item1" as it is in the list. From here the user changes it to "Item4". How would I update the list from that? Does it update automatically if it's set to TwoWay?

I know in the code if I were to change a value in the list, say:

```
Items[2] = "Item4";
```

I can update the textbox by calling

```
RaisePropertyChanged("TextSource3");
```

But that's not of much help to me at the moment.

Comment: Sorry, but what is the question?

Comment: @Bolu Did you read the entire thing? I asked: "Say the displayed value in the first textbox is currently "Item1" as it is in the list. From here the user changes it to "Item4". How would I update the list from that? Does it update automatically if it's set to TwoWay?"

Comment: You need to raise your "RaisePropertyChanged" event in your property set

Comment: @Bolu I haven't had a chance to try it yet as the code in the actual application is much bulkier and I didn't originally implement it like this so I have no way of knowing as of yet. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: @Shane.C Won't that just make the textbox "Item1" from the value in the list again? I want to update the list from the textbox. Not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things to note. First when by default, a `TextBox` won't propagate the text changes until it loses focus. This can happen if you tab out of the control, or click on another control that can receive focus (like the other `TextBoxes`).

You can change this behavior by setting the [`UpdateSourceTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx) on the `Binding` (you also don't *need* `Mode=TwoWay` on a `TextBox` as it is the default mode):

```
<TextBox Name="TextBox1" text="{Binding TextSource1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

The second is that your properties need to raise the `PropertyChanged` event in their setter. While this isn't strictly necessary for a single `Binding` to work, you will want to do it in case you decide to have other controls bound to the same property.

Answer (score 1):

Change type of Items to `ObserableCollection<String>`

Change binding of textbox to:

```
<TextBox Name="TextBox1" text="{Binding Items[0], Mode=TwoWay}">
<TextBox Name="TextBox2" text="{Binding Items[1], Mode=TwoWay}">
<TextBox Name="TextBox3" text="{Binding Items[2], Mpde=TwoWay}">
```

Because of ObservableCollection's internal notification mechanism, when you modify one of its element, it will notify UI.

Comment: I like your answer but I was looking for a way to update the element from the UI. Not a way to update the UI from the element.

Comment: You absolutely can update data on ViewModel from TextBox. The question is whether you want additional logic in notification from UI. Benefit of using separate properties wrapping collection index is you can add some logic in setters. If binding directly applies on collection, you have to add an event listener. However, I did not see this case in your code.

Answer (score 0):

> Say the displayed value in the first textbox is currently "Item1" as it is in the list. From here the user changes it to "Item4". How would I update the list from that? Does it update automatically if it's set to TwoWay?

Yes it updates automatically when it loss focus.